# My loss is either 0.0 or randomly very high - Tensorflow

Tags: neural-networks, python, deep-learning, loss-functions, tensorflow

I am making a CNN with 6 classes. The 8400 training samples are batched into 84 batches of size 100. I run the model and print out the loss after every batch, the loss is always either 0.0 or some arbitrary number in scientific notation such as 1.74463e+06. Is this normal or am i doing something terrible wrong?

`def train_network(x):
    pred = convolutional_network(x)
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels = y, logits = pred))`

```
train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01).minimize(loss)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer()) # Initialize all the variables
    saver = tf.train.Saver()

    print("RUNNING SESSION...")
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        train_batch_x = []
        train_batch_y = []
        for i in range(0, 84):
            train_batch_x = BATCHES_IMAGES[i]
            train_batch_y = BATCHES_LABELS[i]

            print('Starting feed_dict on batch ', i)
            _, loss_value = sess.run([train_op, loss], feed_dict={x: train_batch_x, y: train_batch_y})
            print('Finished batch --- loss: ', loss_value)
        print('Epoch : ', epoch+1, ' of ', num_epochs, ' - Loss: ', loss_value)

    correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
    acc = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, 'float'))
    print('Accuracy:', acc)

    save_path = saver.save(sess, MODEL_PATH)
    print("Model saved in file: " , save_path)
```

```

When printing the output i get something like this:

[image]

Comment: Update: i added all the loss values for each batch and displayed them after each epoch, it does seem to be decreasing like it should. Talked to a few people on discord and they said sometimes `tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` returns weird results. But the network is training correctly

Answer (score 2):

- Learning rate could be too large - too-large gradients can take large steps across "narrow valleys" and land higher-up on the other side. Try reducing the learning rate.
- Gradient clipping - Sometimes the gradient vector is very long. Gradient clipping reduces this and can help stabilize network training.